# Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_ACCEPT"

Tags: php, http

Please help, this warning only happened when I use moblie device check my blog website, and PHP version is 8, the warning code is:

```
function is_webp():bool{
    return (isset($_COOKIE["su_webp"]) || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp'));
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php shows what can be available in $_SERVER..the one you've used isn't listed.

Comment: You should code for something like that not being set.  `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ?? null`

Comment: Thanks, I am new in PHP,  and I am not sure whether this function necessary

Comment: The idea of the function seems to be to check whether the client will accept data in webp format. It's up to you whether you think that's necessary, in the context of your application and the request that this code is trying to process.